# Recover a deleted repository github enterprise

Tags: github, repository, recovery

How to recover deleted repository for a github organization, Under organization >> settings am not able to find the deleted repositories as mentioned here https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/restoring-a-deleted-repository#restoring-a-deleted-repository-that-was-owned-by-an-organization

am using `GitHub Enterprise Server 2.19.15`

Is there a workaround for this. restoring the repo?

Answer (score 0):

The Deleted repos list is shown after 90 mints of deleting. I was able to restore the repository.
I am posting this because it might help sombody like me